# Upload media file failed. Uploadtest failed

Tags: images, uploads

When i want to upload a media file in wordpress (dashbord media) i get the message:  Uploading “” failed.
The file failed the upload test.

php version: 8.0.30

Is there a string/variable that must be changed?

Comment: can you add more detail? There's no code in your question to debug and it's not clear where you uploaded the file, what the file was, if it has always been broken, etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.